# Whats wrong with this regex to remove substring?

Tags: javascript, regex, extract

Trying to strip out the extra addressee from an address string. In the example below, `dba bobs` is the targeted string to remove.

```
const NOT_EXTRA_ADDRESSEE = /^(?!.*(attn|co|dba|fka|dept).*\n).*\n/gim;

"bobs burgers dba bobs dinner\n100 Oceanside drive\nnashville, tn 37204"
  .replace(NOT_EXTRA_ADDRESSEE, "");
```

The above yields:

```
bobs burgers dba bobs dinner
100 oceanside drive
nashville tn 37204
```

When the desired is:

```
bobs burgers
100 oceanside drive
nashville tn 37204
```

What am I doing wrong? Sometimes the input has a '\n' before the 'dba'.

Comment: I would not expect `^` which means start of string

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\s*\b(?:attn|co|dba|fka|dept)\b.*/, "");` should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your regex to: `/\b(attn|co|dba|fka|dept)\b.*/gm`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/TOH9VV/2

```js
const regex = /\b(attn|co|dba|fka|dept)\b.*/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('\\b(attn|co|dba|fka|dept)\\b.*', 'gm')

const str = `bobs burgers dba bobs
100 Oceanside drive
nashville, tn 37204

bobs burgers dba bobs
100 attn Oceanside drive
nashville, tn 37204

bobs burgers dba bobs
100 Oceanside depth drive
nashville, tn fka 37204`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

EDIT:
Included suggestion of user Cary Swoveland in the comments.

Comment: You may wish to: 1) add word boundaries to avoid matching, for example `'tacos'` (returning `'ta'`) or `'out of his depth'` (returning `'out of his '`); 2) replace `[^\n]` (`[\r\n]` preferred) with `.`; and 3) change the capture group to a non-capture group: `\b(?:attn|co|dba|fka|dept)\b.*/gm`. The capture group works fine but may signal to the user that you intend to use the captured string, which you will not be doing.

Comment: I am marking this as as the answer (and thank you @CarySwoveland).  In avoiding a somewhat redundant question, how can I match on a preceeding '\n' such as "bob's burgers\n d/b/a bobs dinner\n100 Oceanside Drive" ` /\\n+\S*\b(attn|co| ....` fails.

Comment: /[\n\r].*\b(attn|co|

Comment: @Tom try `\s*\b(attn...` this will match any preceding white space char, including newlines and other line delimiters.